# Фільм, кіно, стрічка,кінофільм. Чи тотожні ці слова?

Tags: синоніми

Часто в розмовній мові, щоб уникнути тавтології, люди вживають ці три слова як взаємозамінні. [*документальна стрічка*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0), [кінофільм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC).

Comment: можна не тільки приймати відповіді, а й голосувати стрілочкою вгору, якщо вони вам подобаються. так користувач отримає ще більше рейтинґу і ще більше захоче відповідати на питання далі.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Згідно із [Словником синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC)

> ***КІНОФІ́ЛЬМ, КІНОКАРТИ́НА, ФІЛЬМ, СТРІ́ЧКА, КІНО́ (розм.), КАРТИ́НА (розм.), ПЛІ́ВКА (розм.)*** *Кожної суботи в училищному
>   клубі новий кінофільм* (І. Багмут); *Все, що тут написано, в майбутню
>   кінокартину, звичайно, не ввійде* (О. Довженко); *Ландшафт мінився
>   щохвилини. Сергій мовчки пірнав у глиб берегів, і йому здавалося, що
>   дивився він зараз найцікавіший фільм* (Г. Епік); *Автори стрічки
>   ["Тіні забутих предків"] зуміли показати яскраві картини життя і
>   побуту старої Гуцульщини* (з журналу); *Вже було пізненько і кіно,
>   мабуть, уже давно закінчилося* (Григорій Тютюнник); *Праворуч -
>   Нотр-Дам. І синерама, де в кіносеансах Паризьку плівку демонструють
>   нам* (Л. Дмитерко).

***Кіно, фільм, стрічка*** можемо вважати повними синонімами.

Зокрема в СУМ представлені всі три слова:

> **[СТРІЧКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/strichka)** Те саме, що кінофільм.
>
> **[КІНОФІЛЬМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/kinofiljm)** Твір кінематографії, призначений для показування на екрані; кінокартина.
>
> [**КІНО**](http://sum.in.ua/s/KINO) 1. Кінематографія, кіномистецтво. 2. розм. Те саме, що
>   кінофільм.

***В усній мові можемо вживати всі ці слова, як взаємозамінні.***